# To retain form values such as dropdown and radio buttons without using any webstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and wanted to retain its values when form loads without using any web storage.

I want to use only Javascript or jQuery. Moreover, I want that form values such as radio and dropdown selected value should retain its previous filled values.

Comment: Love how people use the phrase "javascript OR jquery". jQuery is a javascript library, how do you use jQuery without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use browser cache or cookies to retain data on the client side. But both have their own limitations. [Smartphone Browser native cache is about 5x times slower than local storage](http://www.mobify.com/blog/smartphone-localstorage-outperforms-browser-cache/) and information about cookies is sent to the server in the request header when a user visits a page that has cookies associated with it.